# id_rsa not visible in Jenkins pipeline but available on server

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I am trying to do SSH from Jenkins to remote server. I have added id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys of remote server to make it password less SSH. I am able to do SSH from server where Jenkins is installed withour password by `ssh user@REMOTE_IP`.

When I do `ls -lrta /root/.ssh/` on Jenkins server I can see `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` but if I run same command in Jenkins Pipeline I cannot see those files. I can only see `authorized_keys`.

Because of this when I run pipeline I get following error

```
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in your log, the ssh key is under /root, Jenkins user probably doesn't have read access there. (use "ls -ltr /root" to view permission)

1. You should create /home/jenkins/.ssh folder and provide jenkins user permissions there.
2. (not recommended) Give jenkins permissions to access the /root/.ssh file. This is possible using "chmod +r /root/.ssh/id_rsa"